# BeautifulSoup </div> scraping suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some `div`s from a NASA website and put all the contents in a list. **THIS CODE WAS WORKING EARLIER** and has suddenly decided not to. I didn't change anything knowingly except to add some print statements, all of which return nothing or `[]` with no error of any kind.

```
import re
import urllib2 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as soup
import ssl


url = "https://climate.nasa.gov"
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
web_soup = soup(urllib2.urlopen(url,  context=context))

l = []

# get main-content div
main_div = web_soup.findAll(name="div", attrs={'class': 'change_number'})
print main_div
for element in main_div:
    print element
    l.append(float(str(element)[27:-7]))

print l
```

Any help with pinpointing this sudden error would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE1**: Just tried it in the interpreter, fails in the same way. `main_div` seems to be returning `[]`.

**UPDATE2**: Just checked the website to ensure that the div `change_number` exists. It does.

**UPDATE3**: Now I am really confused. I have this code, which I am pretty sure is basically identical to the one above:

```
import re
import urllib2 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as soup
import ssl


url = "https://climate.nasa.gov"
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
web_soup = soup(urllib2.urlopen(url,  context=context))

l = []

# get main-content div
main_div = web_soup.findAll(name="div", attrs={'class': 'change_number'})
for element in main_div:
    print element
    l.append(float(str(element)[27:-7]))

print l
```

But it is throwing a `UnicodeEncodeError` on the websoup definition line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "climate_nasa_change.py", line 10, in <module>
    web_soup = soup(urllib2.urlopen(url,  context=context))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1522, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1147, in __init__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1189, in _feed
    SGMLParser.feed(self, markup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sgmllib.py", line 104, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sgmllib.py", line 143, in goahead
    k = self.parse_endtag(i)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sgmllib.py", line 320, in parse_endtag
    self.finish_endtag(tag)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sgmllib.py", line 358, in finish_endtag
    method = getattr(self, 'end_' + tag)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**UPDATE4**: aaaaaaaaaaaaaand now its magically working. I really have no idea what the hell is going on right now.

**UPDATE5**: and now its broken. I swear I am not changing. Seriously considering exorcising my computer. Please help.

**UPDATE6**: Just tried pinging climate.nasa.gov. It doesn't always go through, despite the page consistently loading in my browser. Could this be causing BeautifulSoup to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the site sometimes returns a gzip encoded response and other times plaintext.
You can resolve this easily if you use `requests` , as it decodes the content automatically :

```
web_soup = soup(requests.get(url, verify=False).text)
```

Note that `requests` is not a standard lib, you have to install it.
If you insist on using `urllib2` you can decode the response with `zlib` if it's encoded :

```
decode = lambda response : zlib.decompress(response, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS) 
response = urllib2.urlopen(url,  context=context)
headers = response.info()
html = decode(response.read()) if headers.get('content-encoding') == 'gzip' else response
web_soup = soup(html)
```

Comment: I get error `requests not defined`. Is requests a separate module or within BeautifulSoup?